# Fragment must be public static class to be properly recreated from instance state

Tags: java, android, static, fragment

I try to have a fragment with some business logic but when it launches I get the following error

> Fragment must be public static class to be properly recreated from
>   instance state

I found some similar questions but the answers did not help in my case as I do not have a nested / anomynous class I could make static (or am I missing something?)

How can I solve this issue?

...

```
class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public OverviewFragment(){
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        loadRecords();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    }

    public void drawCategoryChart(Map<String,Integer> categories) {
        ...
    }
    public void drawUserChart(...) {
        ...
    }
    public void loadRecords(){
        List<Record> records = 
AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).recordDao().getAll();
        ...
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.spendingOverview);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new RecordOverviewRecycleListAdapter(records);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    // Returns Map of all categories with their respective sums of all transactions
    public Map<String,Integer> getCategorySums(List<Record> records){
        Map<String,Integer> catSums = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Record r : records){
            if (!catSums.containsKey(r.getCategory())){
                catSums.put(r.getCategory(),r.getAmount());
            } else {
                catSums.put(r.getCategory(),catSums.get(r.getCategory())+r.getAmount());
            }
        }
        return catSums;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `OverviewFragment` an inner class of another object?

Comment: I added the adapter where its used, otherwise it is not used anywhere else

Comment: What file contains `class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {...}`?

Comment: Its a top level class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your top level file is not visible by Android Framework to be managed by the `FragmentManager`.

```
class OverviewFragment extends Fragment
```

You need to make your class **public**. Not package default, as you have it right now. Your Fragment should be defined next.

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment
```

Comment: @NicoMüller Yeah, this happens)